# New Car Stereo Not Saving Stations

Tags: audio, citroen

I have put in an aftermarket stereo into my car. (Pioneer DEH-4500BT).

I hooked it all up ok and it was all working. However i noticed that it did not turn off with the engine.

Before i had brought it i had read up about changing stereos so i knew what this was.

I got a friend of mine to wire the Cigarette lighter to the "Switched 12v".

Now it turns on and off with the car.

However, when i turn off the car and leave it for about 30 minutes, the radio stations that i have saved disappear.

Is there any way to fix this?

The car is a Citroen C3 - 1.1i Petrol - 2004 (04).

PS. My friend is a Car Electrical Specialist, but has gone on holiday for a month today!!
He also checked correctly which one was permanent live and which was switched live.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the head-unit is hooked up to constant power (usually the yellow wire on the harness). Make sure that it isn't hooked to a circuit that goes off after half an hour or when you open the door.

Comment: Exactly, you need to get a constant power to keep the memory between each shutdown/start-up. The constant power wire will draw really few amps that will not drain your battery.

Comment: Some cars don't have a "constant power wire in the audio system loom. I had the same thing with my Opel Corsa. The guys who installed the system had to run a new wire from somewhere.

Comment: It is all wired correctly. The constant and the switched were both tested with a volt meter to check which ones were which

Comment: @Dr.Pepper chances are that the constant power isn't actually a constant power. Maybe a 30 minute power. Where are you getting the lead from a random loom or fuse box?

Comment: hi mate, the switched 12v is coming from the cigarrette lighter and the constant is coming from the original loom with a harness on the end which came with radio

Comment: With the vehicle off try pressing the power on the headunit most will display the clock only with the power off. Try again after half an hour without starting the car is the clock still showing? If not it is probably a wiring issue meaning something is cutting power to the unit. If the clock still displays but is reset/wrong then it is probably the headunit itself.

Comment: Had a go at it with the multimeter. The constant live seems to turn off after about 5 minutes for some reason. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @Dr.Pepper Because it isn't a constant live... for some reason it is a delayed turn off. Probably because the factory radio is allowed to play for five minutes after the vehicle is turned off if the person wants to. After that they have to start the car so as to not kill the battery.

Comment: How would I go about sorting my current situation then mate?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

[image: http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/StaticFiles/Manuals/Car/DEH-X6500BT_OwnersManual112712.pdf]

http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/StaticFiles/Manuals/Car/DEH-X6500BT_OwnersManual112712.pdf

Black to Ground

Yellow to "always on"  (battery, fuse protected)  {saves memory}

Red to ignition

Blue/White to external amplifier (or insulated)

Orange (optional) to park lights

Comment: It is all wired correctly. The constant and the switched were both tested with a volt meter to check which ones were which

Comment: If, after half an hour or so, the yellow wire is still at 12V (or better) and the radio ground is solidly connected, I'd suspect a faulty radio.   Let us know!!   :)

Comment: im gonna get the volt meter out and have a check i think at some point lol

Comment: I'd be grabbing the voltmeter about the second or third time I had to reprogram in the stations!!!   (grin)

Comment: Had a go at it with the multimeter. The constant live seems to turn off after about 5 minutes for some reason. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: 5 minutes? No, I don't have a clue unless it's a "feature" to prevent the user from running down the battery with accessories.  I tried to locate your vehicle wiring diagram and failed, couldn't find a pre-made adapter between your car radio factory  wiring and your specific radio either. You've located the problem so now you can apply a solution, which is to locate a 12V feed that is always on.  Good job!!  Let us know!

Comment: Right. Finally got to the bottom of it.
Bare with me with this one.
Red wire = Ignition
Yellow wire = permanent (Supposedly)

Found out the yellow wire turned off after 5 minutes. Began testing other wires. When i tested 1 wire, it then turned the Yellow back on, car made an electrical noise. The same noise it makes when going into eco mode.

The other wire i tested was permanent live. So clipped and crimped the new permanent live to the yellow wire from the radio and all was well...

Basically, the adapter from the car to the radio was wrong. lol

Comment: Very excellent news, Dr. Pepper!! Congratulations!!